# SQL query order by top category follow by subcategory

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 1 category table which has parent_id field in it.. parent_id can contain category id so we know its sub catgeory. 
parent_id = 0 means it is top level category

i want to write a single query to order by top category first, then all subcategories of that top category, then all sub-subcategories of that top category. does any one has any idea on this.

Thanks

Sampe data

```
CategoryId      |   CategoryName    |   Parent_id
1                   cat A               0
2                   cat B               0
3                   cat C               0
4                   cat D               0
5                   cat A A             1
6                   cat A B             1
7                   cat A A A           5
8                   cat A A B           5
9                   cat B A             2
10                  cat B B             2
11                  cat B C             2
12                  cat B D             2
```

The result should be like:

```
CategoryId      |   CategoryName    |   Parent_id
1                   cat A               0
5                   cat A A             1
7                   cat A A A           5
8                   cat A A B           5
6                   cat A B             1
2                   cat B               0
9                   cat B A             2
10                  cat B B             2
11                  cat B C             2
12                  cat B D             2
3                   cat C               0
4                   cat D               0
```

Comment: @user3025605, the result set is little confusing with your question. please see once again the results part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (categoryID int,CategoryName varchar(50),parent_id int)
Insert into @YourTable values 
(1 ,'cat A',    0),
(2 ,'cat B',    0),
(3 ,'cat C',    0),
(4 ,'cat D',    0),
(5 ,'cat A A',  1),
(6 ,'cat A B',  1),
(7 ,'cat A A A',5),
(8 ,'cat A A B',5),
(9 ,'cat B A',  2),
(10,'cat B B',  2),
(11,'cat B C',  2),
(12,'cat B D',  2)

Declare @Top  int = null             --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 5
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with ctePt as (
      Select Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by CategoryName) as varchar(500))
            ,categoryID
            ,parent_id
            ,Lvl=1
            ,CategoryName 
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,0) = case when @Top is null then isnull(parent_id,0) else categoryID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',100000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.CategoryName)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.categoryID
            ,r.parent_id,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.CategoryName 
      From   @YourTable r 
      Join   ctePt p  on r.parent_id = p.categoryID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,categoryID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From ctePt)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.categoryID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.categoryID )
Select B.R1  
      ,C.R2
      ,A.categoryID
      ,A.parent_id
      ,A.Lvl
      ,CategoryName = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.CategoryName
 From ctePt A
 Join cteR1 B on A.categoryID=B.categoryID
 Join cteR2 C on A.categoryID=C.categoryID
 Order By B.R1
```

Returns

[image]

Now, you may notice R1/R2.  These are the Range Keys.  I find them useful in navigating and aggregated data up the hierarchy.  If you don't need them, remove cteR1 and cteR2 and set the final Order By A.Seq

> **Just for fun, if you set @Top=5, you'll get**

[image]

Comment: @user3025605 Happy it helped