# How to set an order when using CTE?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table with 2 columns (id, childId). The data is as follows:

- 1, 2
- 3, 4
- 2, null
- 4, null

I'm using a CTE so that I get the child records:

```
DECLARE @id TABLE (id int);
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 3;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id, childId
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 
        id IN (SELECT id FROM @id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.childId
    FROM mytable b
    INNER JOIN cte 
        ON b.id = cte.childId
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

The result always come back as:

- 1, 2
- 3, 4
- 4, null
- 2, null

But I need the result to look like:

- 1, 2
- 2, null
- 3, 4,
- 4, null

That is, first the anchor records then the records for the recursive sql for each anchor record.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a static value to in anchor query. Then in recursive part add a static value greater than the static value of anchor query. Now the use static value in `Order by`

Try this

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 0 as rn, id, childId
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 
        id IN (SELECT id FROM @id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as rn,b.id, b.childId
    FROM mytable b
    INNER JOIN cte 
        ON b.id = cte.childId
)
SELECT * FROM cte
Order by rn,id
```

Also consider adding `option(Maxrecursion N)`. By default it just makes only `100` recursions

Answer (score 2):

By Adding a Seq, the results will be displayed in the proper order/nesting

```
DECLARE @id TABLE (id int);
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO @id SELECT 3;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id, childId
          ,Seq  = cast(100000+Row_Number() over (Order by id) as varchar(500))
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 
        id IN (SELECT id FROM @id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.childId
          ,Seq  = cast(concat(cte.Seq,'.',100000+Row_Number() over (Order by b.id)) as varchar(500))
    FROM mytable b
    INNER JOIN cte 
        ON b.id = cte.childId
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
Order By Seq
```

Comment: I didn't get the logic behind `100000` in `Row_number` is that really needed ? I don't think so

Comment: @Prdp Consistency in sequencing. 1,10,2  vs 10001,10002,10010

Comment: @Prdp Moot point :) , but I use this string to build range keys  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250197/sql-query-order-by-top-category-follow-by-subcategory/41250489#41250489